# Android get week day names between two dates

Tags: java, android, date, dayofweek, difference

I want to get day names between two dates with simple Java, without using any third party library.

I want to get names like Saturday, Sunday, Monday between two days inclusive both.

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
     * 
     * @param startDate
     * @param endDate
     * @return Start Date and End Date are <b>Inclusive</b>, days returned between these two dates
     */
    protected List<String> getWeekDayNames(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
        List<String> days = new ArrayList<String>();

        Calendar startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        startCal.setTime(startDate);

        Calendar endCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        endCal.setTime(endDate);

        if (startCal.getTimeInMillis() == endCal.getTimeInMillis()) {

            days.add(this.formatDayOfWeek(startCal.getTime()));

            return Collections.unmodifiableList(days);
        }
        // swap values
        if (startCal.getTimeInMillis() > endCal.getTimeInMillis()) {
            startCal.setTime(endDate);
            endCal.setTime(startDate);
        }

        do {

            days.add(this.formatDayOfWeek(startCal.getTime()));

            startCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

        } while (startCal.getTimeInMillis() <= endCal.getTimeInMillis());

        return Collections.unmodifiableList(days);
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 15);

        List<String> list = new Test().getWeekDayNames(new Date(), cal.getTime());

        System.out.println(list);
```

**Output:**

```
[SATURDAY, SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY]
```

Comment: I think you missed formatDayOfWeek in your Answer. Please add that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Joda-Time

Usually I would suggest the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, a popular replacement for the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date & java.util.Calendar classes bundled with Java. But the Question requires no third-party libraries.

## java.time.*

So, instead of Joda-Time, my code example below uses the new [java.time.* package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/index.html?java/time/package-summary.html) bundled with [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8). These classes are inspired by Joda-Time, but are entirely re-architected. They are defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). For more information, see the [new Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) from Oracle.

The solution is quite simple. Boils down to this one-line fragment…

```
DayOfWeek.from( zonedDateTime ).getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL, Locale.US );
```

For fun, I tossed in an extra line to show how easy it is to localize. In this case I show the French as well as US English word for day-of-week.

Here is the entire snippet, ready to run if you import `java.time.*` and `java.time.format.*`.

```
ZoneId timeZone = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" );

ZonedDateTime start = ZonedDateTime.now( timeZone );
ZonedDateTime stop = start.plusDays( 2 );

// Usually spans of time are handled in a "half-open" manner, meaning start is inclusive and stop is exclusive.
// But the Question required both start and stop to be inclusive. So add "1".
long days = java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( start, stop ) + 1L;

System.out.println( days + " days from " + start + " to " + stop + " inclusive…");
for ( int i = 0; i < days; i++ ) {
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = start.plusDays( i );
    String dayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.from( zonedDateTime ).getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL, java.util.Locale.US );
    String dayOfWeek_Français = DayOfWeek.from( zonedDateTime ).getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL, java.util.Locale.FRENCH );
    System.out.println( "zonedDateTime: " + zonedDateTime + "  dayOfWeek: " + dayOfWeek + "  dayOfWeek_Français: " + dayOfWeek_Français );
}
```

When run…

```
3 days from 2014-02-08T06:06:33.335-05:00[America/New_York] to 2014-02-10T06:06:33.335-05:00[America/New_York] inclusive…
zonedDateTime: 2014-02-08T06:06:33.335-05:00[America/New_York]  dayOfWeek: Saturday  dayOfWeek_Français: samedi
zonedDateTime: 2014-02-09T06:06:33.335-05:00[America/New_York]  dayOfWeek: Sunday  dayOfWeek_Français: dimanche
zonedDateTime: 2014-02-10T06:06:33.335-05:00[America/New_York]  dayOfWeek: Monday  dayOfWeek_Français: lundi
```